# How to open IE with code?

Tags: automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

In my test, I can automatically open IE with:

```
public void OpenIEtoAppURL()
{
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("iexplore", "www.google.ca");
}
```

Will this work on other computers that may not have admin access? Will this method cause false alarms for a virus?

I'm not sure if this is the best way to open IE, any improvements are appreciated.

Note: the target users are people who aren't good with computers so I don't want to alarm them with authorization checks.

I'm trying to make some kind of executable so that they can just click on it and it will run a suite of automated tests for specific web applications on a weekly basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will work, but it's the wrong way to do it.

Instead, you should open the URL itself:

```
Process.Start("https://google.com");
```

This will open the page in the user's default browser.
Note that the protocol is required.

Comment: Never knew you could do that. I'll look into protocols.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish?  You mention people who are not good with computers but your tags are for testing.  Do you have non-technical people running automated tests?

If you want IE ONLY, you could try ShDocVw.InternetExplorer.